# Multiple models in Application route, how to setup the controller Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So i've got this in my

Application Route

```
App.ApplicationRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            projects: this.store.find('project'),
            departments: this.store.find('department'),
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

Application Controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    all_projects: Ember.computed.alias('model.projects'),
    all_departments: Ember.computed.alias('model.departments'),
});
```

Then I have this in my template

```
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding:0">
        {{view Ember.Select class="form-control cover-input" content=all_projects value=create_project}}
    </div>
        {{view Ember.Select class="form-control half-input" content=all_departments optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.department_name" value=create_department}}
```

But nothing appears in the select box. I've also tried just looping through the property like so

`{{#each all_departments}} {{department_name}} {{/each}}` doesn't show anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Your model alias all_projects and all_departments will be an array object. So your should extend ArrayController for your ApplicationController instead of extending ObjectController.

Hope that will solve the issue of loading the Ember.Select view.

Given below an basic example of multiple model with Ember.Select view to render the two models.

[JSBIN Ling](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/roziy/1/)

Comment: Sure those are arrays but the model itself is returning an Object of two arrays. So doing `App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend` gives me an error as it should. `Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object`.